# Minkowski's theory on lattices

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have just started reading Algebraic number theory, and I am finding the Minkowski's theory of lattices present in Jurgen Neurich, hard to understand. I think, I am missing some prerequisites. Can anyone refer me a better source to study this.

Comment: there are several introductory books, usual title is Geometry of Numbers

Comment: https://books.google.co.vi/books?id=aXX5sgEACAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: Milne's notes (freely available from his webpage) are a good resource (on many subjects, including this one).